# Angular 10: Table row as a component, misalignment of table data

Tags: html, angular

I have this problem:
I have a table that displays some cars and Edit/Delete buttons;
I want every table row to be a car component.
Instead of

```
<tr *ngFor="let car of filteredCars">
  <td> {{car.Brand }}
  ..
  <td> <button> Edit </button> </td>
  <td> <button> Delete </button> </td>
</tr>
```

I need to display the car properties using a car component.
So I created my component as following:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'car-component',
    template: `
        <td> {{Brand}} </td>
        <td> {{Model}} </td>
        <td> {{Power}} </td>
    `
})
export class CarComponent { 
    @Input() CarId: number;
    @Input() Brand: string;
    @Input() Model: string;
    @Input() Power: string;
}
```

The problem is when I try to

```
 <tr *ngFor="let car of filteredCars">
 <car-component [CarId]="car.CarId" [Brand]="car.Brand" [Model]="car.Model" 
     [Power]="car.Power">
 </car-component>
//buttons
 </tr>
```

The content of the car component is displayed in the first data cell of the table row:

[image]

I understand that he takes the whole car component as the first , the problem is I can't manage to achieve the solution.
I tried: using templates / directive.

Answer (score -1):

First of all you don't need to make a component for just `td`. You can make a component with full `tr` like this

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'car-component',
  template: `
   <tr>
    <td> {{carData.Brand}} </td>
    <td> {{arData.Model}} </td>
    <td> {{arData.CarId}} </td>
   </tr>
 `
 })
export class CarComponent { 
 @Input() carData: any;
}
```

and then you can use your `car component` like this

```
 <car-component [carData]="car" *ngFor="let car of filteredCars">
 </car-component>
```

Comment: Sorry, but this code is just creating a table row with those 3 tds into the first td of table.